# Is it possible to "extend", or re-use, an Eclipse extension point?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an Eclipse RCP application (3.x), which also provides extension points. Up to now, I've simply created a new schema for the extension points, since they are linked to specific application functionalities.

Now, however, I'd like to provide an extension point for new editors. I'd like to use the existing `org.eclipse.ui.editors`, and enhance it with some application-specific behaviour, such as providing a class different from `IEditorPart` that needs to be inherited from.

Is it possible to re-use the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point in another fashion than just copy-and-pasting its `.exsd` file, and changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't change existing extension points.

There is a huge amount of code behind the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point so trying to reproduce this is a big task.

I think you would be better creating additional extension points for your additional functionality in the same way that the Java editor adds new extension points (such as `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorTextHovers`)

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid that this is the case. I'll have a look at `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorTextHovers` and see if I can adapt my setup. On a more funny note: I'd have bet my left hand that it'd be you providing the answer to my question. Thanks for sharing your expertise on many an [tag:eclipse-rcp] question!